# Compressing a video file for a website?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing

How can I compress mp4 video file to be really small size and still maintain good quality. I need the video to loop on a background of a website.

For example this one is only 2.1 MB: http://2.s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/2021746.mp4

Comment: Your video specs: MP4, h264/avc1/yuv420p, 960x540, 23.98 fps, audio aac/mp4a at 44,1kHz. Use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to encode your videos according to these specs.

Answer (score 0):

Your video is already h.264, what you can do is, reduce the width and height, bring down the audio quality and also re-encode with a lower framerate (maybe 15fps), there are a lot of tools to encode, other than the free ffmpeg, but they are paid tools.

I wouldnt suggest setting a video as a 'background' of a website.

Hope this helps.